# Multiple optional params matching

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hi everyone I'm facing an issue with react router. Actually I'm using react-router 5.2.0

What I want to achieve is to have same base route with different parameters, and retrieve correct parameter within the component that match the route.

For example, I have two routes like this:

```
<Route
        path={["/search", "/search/:city?", "/search/:province?"]}
        exact
        render={(props: any) => <Search {...props} />}
      />
```

On the Search component what I want to achive is to get the parameter and what type of parameter is, city or province. But react router seems to catch only the first route "/search/:city?" even if I'm in the province route.
I thought that generatePath ([react router doc](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/generatePath)), could save my day, but it doesn't work as i expected. Or better is not really generatePath itself, but more the route matching pattern.
Just to clarify better i made a codesandbox,[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-platform-ujcob), as you can see if you click on one of the link with province, react router will catch the parameter correctly, but as "type" city not province.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure your url like `/search?type=city` and handle the process that you want to achieve in **Search** component when it mounts with query params.

Comment: I thought the same (and I also had a solution implemented for that kind of url), but I want to have a more "SEO friendly url"